# Calling a dll from fortran

Tags: dll, g++, mingw, fortran

I am aiming at calling a dll file from a fortran compiler. I am doing all this in **windows** using the **mingw** compiler.

The dll was created using a g++ compiler

**The code for which I am trying to create a dll**

```
// example_dll.cpp  
#include <stdio.h>
#include "example_dll.h"

__stdcall void hello()
{
        printf("Hello");
}
```

**command entered in the command prompt**

```
g++ -c -DBUILDING_EXAMPLE_DLL example_dll.cpp

g++ -shared -o example_dll.dll example_dll.o -Wl,--out-implib,libexample_dll.a
```

The above two commands creates the dll file.

The job now is to create a fortran script to compile the dll file previously created.

For this purpose I am looking forward to create a fortran file capable of linking to the dll previously created.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Adarsh

Answer (score 0):

Later I tried some of the possibilities. My updated files are as follows

**C file for which the DLL is created is as follows**

```
// example_dll.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "example_dll.h"

EXPORT void tstfunc (void)
{
  printf("Hello\n");
}

EXPORT int Double11(int x)
{
    printf("From the Double11\n");
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return x;
}
```

**.h file used to create the DLL is as follows**

```
// example_dll.h
#ifdef EXAMPLE_DLL_H
// the dll exports
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
// the exe imports
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// function to be imported/exported
EXPORT void tstfunc (void);

EXPORT int Double11(int x);
```

**Fortran file used to link the dll is as follows**

```
! fortcall.f90
program ForCall
    IMPLICIT NONE
    integer :: sum
    integer :: inte3 
    INTERFACE
        SUBROUTINE write() BIND(C,NAME='tstfunc')
        END SUBROUTINE write
        END INTERFACE
    INTERFACE       
        SUBROUTINE get_integer(inte,inte2) BIND(C,NAME='Double11')
        USE ISO_C_BINDING
        IMPLICIT NONE
        INTEGER (C_INT), VALUE :: inte
        INTEGER (C_INT), INTENT(OUT) :: inte2
        END SUBROUTINE get_integer
    END INTERFACE
    CALL write    
    CALL get_integer(1,inte3)
    print*,"the output is",inte3
END PROGRAM ForCall
```

After entering the following directive in the command prompt

**gfortran -o dll_foo_test fortcall.f90 -L. example_dll.dll**

The output will be as follows

```
Hello
From the Double11
1
 the output is -2
```

At this point something is not right. **The code is capable of passing a value from FORTRAN to the DLL, whereas the code is not returning the right value from the dll.** Some junk value of -2 is being displayed instead of 1.

I would like to fix that part in the code.